# Limit viewing to map boundary on Android

Tags: openstreetmap, java, android

I have an offline map of a city displaying on Android. Since my map is just small, when you scroll beyond the the boundaries of the map you see only a gray screen and you will probably be lost and could not be able to view the city map.

How can I limit the viewing of the map to the boundaries of the city map?

What should I do for the user to only scroll on the map area, and not beyond it?

My resources are OSM Mapnik, osmdroid-android-3.0.1.jar library.